# An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
m_Set.ClearQueryInfo();
m_Set.SetParameterWhere("PatID = @PatIDParam AND EffectiveEnrollmentDate IN (Select MAX(EffectiveEnrollmentDate))");
m_Set.SetWhere("PatID = ? AND EffectiveEnrollmentDate IN (Select MAX(EffectiveEnrollmentDate))");
m_Set.SetNumParams(1);
m_Set.SetParam("@PatIDParam", 1, PatIDParam.ToString());
```

but I end up receiving the following error:

> *An aggregate may not appear in the
>   WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause
>   or a select list, and the column being
>   aggregated is an outer reference,
>   SELECT dbo.[PatRoster].* FROM
>   dbo.[PatRoster]  WHERE PatID =
>   @PatIDParam AND
>   EffectiveEnrollmentDate IN (Select
>   MAX(EffectiveEnrollmentDate))*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not valid - `Select MAX(EffectiveEnrollmentDate)` is not complete; it has to select `EffectiveEnrollmentDate` from somewhere in that subquery.

Also, `MAX()` only ever returns a single value, so there is no need for `IN` - you can just do straight comparison operator `=`.

Comment: Thanks :) A bit early that I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 2):

You're not specifying the table source to query from here:

```
(Select MAX(EffectiveEnrollmentDate))
```

Change it to:

```
(Select MAX(EffectiveEnrollmentDate) FROM PatRoster)
```

Comment: Thanks :) A bit early that I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, the correct way to do this is with a subquery:

```
select bar.foo
from bar
where bar.foo = (select max(subbar.foo) from bar as subbar); -- subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

The subquery: `(Select MAX(EffectiveEnrollmentDate))` lacks a source, it cannot refer to the outer query

```
SELECT dbo.[PatRoster].* 
FROM dbo.[PatRoster] 
WHERE PatID = @PatIDParam AND EffectiveEnrollmentDate = (Select MAX(EffectiveEnrollmentDate) FROM dbo.[PatRoster])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an agregate in a sub query over the values of outer query:

`AND EffectiveEnrollmentDate IN (Select MAX(EffectiveEnrollmentDate))`

What you want to do is this:

```
SELECT dbo.[PatRoster].*
  FROM dbo.[PatRoster]
 WHERE PatID = @PatIDParam
   AND EffectiveEnrollmentDate = (Select MAX(EffectiveEnrollmentDate)
                                    FROM dbo.[PatRoster]
                                   WHERE PatID = @PatIDParam)
```