# SQL - An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

If you see the picture below, I only want to see those categories where the average revenue is greater than the overall average.

[image]

The query that I'm using is below. The very last line is causing the issue.

```
WITH cte_avg AS (
    SELECT P.prod_cat, Avg_revenue = AVG(CAST(T.total_amt AS NUMERIC))
    FROM [dbo].[Transactions] AS T
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[prod_cat_info] AS P ON T.prod_cat_code=P.prod_cat_code
    GROUP BY P.prod_cat
)
SELECT prod_cat, Avg_revenue
FROM cte_avg
WHERE Avg_revenue > AVG(Avg_revenue)
```

The error that I'm getting is:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Please let me know how I can fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991910/an-aggregate-may-not-appear-in-the-where-clause-unless-it-is-in-a-subquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the query you want to write is something like:

```
select p.prod_cat, t.avg_total_amount
from (
    select prod_cat_code, avg(total_amount) as avg_total_amount
    from transactions
    group by prod_cat_code
    having avg(total_amount) > (select avg(total_amount) from transactions)
) t
inner join prod_cat_info p on p.prod_cat_code = t.prod_cat_code
```

The subquery aggregates transactions by category, compute the average, and compares it against the overall transaction average. Then we just bring the categories table with a join.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest window functions.  It is unclear what you mean by "average total revenue".  If you mean the average of the sums revenue for the products, then:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT P.prod_cat, SUM(total_amount) as total_revenue,
             AVG(SUM(total_amount)) OVER () as avg_total_revenue
      FROM [dbo].[Transactions] T JOIN
           [dbo].[prod_cat_info] P
            ON T.prod_cat_code=P.prod_cat_code
      GROUP BY P.prod_cat
     ) c
WHERE total_revenue > avg_total_revenue;
```

If you mean the product average compared to the overall average:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT P.prod_cat, AVG(total_amount) as avg_revenue,
             SUM(SUM(total_amount)) OVER () / SUM(COUNT(*)) as avg_total_revenue
      FROM [dbo].[Transactions] T JOIN
           [dbo].[prod_cat_info] P
            ON T.prod_cat_code=P.prod_cat_code
      GROUP BY P.prod_cat
     ) c
WHERE avg_revenue > avg_total_revenue
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query resolved my issue.

```
WITH cte_avg AS (SELECT P.prod_cat, Avg_revenue = AVG(CAST(T.total_amt AS NUMERIC))
    FROM [dbo].[Transactions] AS T
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[prod_cat_info] AS P ON T.prod_cat_code=P.prod_cat_code
    GROUP BY P.prod_cat)
    SELECT prod_cat, Avg_revenue
    FROM cte_avg
    WHERE Avg_revenue>(SELECT AVG(Avg_revenue) FROM cte_avg)
```